# how to replace all words from sentences from a pandas column with numbers from a dictionary and then sum them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['bad good better three worst', 'awful best one']})
```

and I have the following dictionary `dc = dict({'bad':-1,'good':1,'better':2,'worst':-3,'awful':-5})`

I would like to replace all the words from the `col` with the numbers that correspond with this word from the `dc` and then sum the numbers.

First I tried the replacement using

```
def replace_words(s, words):
    for k, v in words.items():
        s = s.replace('^'k+'$', v, regex=True)
    return s
```

`df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: [replace_words(i, dc) for i in x.split(' ')])`

but this does not work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
df.col.apply(lambda x: sum([dc.get(i) if dc.get(i) else 0 for i in x.split()]))
```

**Output**

```
0   -1
1   -5
```

---

Note : 
if the word is not found in dc then using 0 value in place, do recommend if it is otherwise since it isn't mentioned

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension with `get` for lookup values with default value `0` and `sum`:

```
df['col'] = [sum(dc.get(x, 0) for x in i.split()) for i in df['col']]
print (df)
   col
0   -1
1   -5
```

Another solution for test values in dict with `in`:

```
df['col'] = [sum(dc.get(x) for x in i.split() if x in dc) for i in df['col']]
```

**Details**:

```
print ([list(dc.get(x, 0) for x in i.split()) for i in df['col']])
[[-1, 1, 2, 0, -3], [-5, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`series.str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find all matching words in the string and using `get()` replace the list of words by dict values:

```
df.col.str.findall('|'.join(dc.keys())).apply(lambda x: sum([dc.get(i,i) for i in x]))
```

---

```
0   -1
1   -5
```

Details:

```
df.col.str.findall('|'.join(dc.keys()))


0    [bad, good, better, worst]
1                       [awful]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.col.str.findall('|'.join(dc.keys())).apply(lambda x: [dc.get(i,i) for i in x])
0    [-1, 1, 2, -3]
1              [-5]
Name: col, dtype: object
```